# How to fix "variable might not have been initialized"

Tags: java

I'm attempting to make a program that will tell the average of three test scores, I've gotten as far as allowing the user to input their three scores, but when it comes to calculating and displaying the average I'm a little stuck. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
 double test1, test2, test3;
 double NUM_TESTS = 3;

 Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);

 String first_test;
 System.out.print("Enter your first test: ");
 first_test = user_input.next();

 String second_test;
 System.out.print("Enter your second test: ");
 second_test = user_input.next();

 String third_test;
 System.out.print("Enter your third test: ");
 third_test = user_input.next();

 double x = (test1 + test2 + test3) / (double)NUM_TESTS;

 String total_tests;
 System.out.print("Your average test it: " + x);
```

Comment: Remove `String total_tests;` and the error should go away.

Comment: Also no need to cast `(double) NUM_TESTS`, it's already a double.

Comment: You don't seem to be assigning anything to `test1`, `test2` or `test3`.  This isn't a problem if they're fields, but if they're local variables, you'll need to give them a value.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem if i were to change the line to something like:  double x = (first_test + second_test + third_test) / NUM_TESTS;   would that allow them to be assigned value based off of user input?

Comment: You'll need some way of converting those `String` values to `double`.  You might have to use `nextDouble` instead of `next` to get the numbers.  Alternatively, you could look into using the `parseDouble` method of the `Double` class to do this.